# Register a new user programmaticaly having id proof

Tags: 7

I want to create a user programatically. But I have a field `id proof` where user can upload files.

But I don't know how to save that file while creating user.

Here is my code

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['values']['name'] = 'robo-user';
$form_state['values']['mail'] = 'robouser@example.com';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass1'] = 'password';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass2'] = 'password';
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Create new account'); 
//need to know about files 

drupal_execute('user_register', $form_state);
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help  you.

In Drupal 7 you can use [file_save_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7) and [file_usage_add](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7).

- **file_save_data** : Saves a file to the specified destination and creates a database entry.
- **file_usage_add** : Records that a module is using a file.

```
    global $user;
    $path = 'C:\...\Downloads\sample images\drupal_7_icon_0.jpg';//local path of id proof image
    $filename = drupal_basename($path);//get filename
    $file_temp = file_get_contents($path);
    //Saves a file to the specified destination and creates a database entry.
    //Dont forget to create id_proof folder inside files folder
    $file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://id_proof/' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

    // Record that the module (in this example, user module) is using the file. 
    file_usage_add($file_temp, 'mymodule_name', 'user', $user->uid);//change the module name

    //Get the values to create new user
    $form_state = array();
    $form_state['values']['name'] = 'robo-user';
    $form_state['values']['mail'] = 'robouser@example.com';
    $form_state['values']['pass']['pass1'] = '1234';
    $form_state['values']['pass']['pass2'] = '1234';
    $form_state['values']['op'] = t('Create new account');
    $form_state['values']['field_user_id_proof'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'] = $file_temp->fid;//change it as per your requirement
    drupal_form_submit('user_register_form', $form_state);
    drupal_set_message('User saved successfully');
```

Comment: $file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://id_proof/' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
 this returns filesize=0

Comment: Can you check the filesize of the file which your are uploading.